# Error "No tidy method for objects of class felm" when using the lfe and broom package

Tags: r, linear-regression, broom, tidytext, lfe

I'm trying to tidy the results of my fixed effects linear regression model. Here's the FELM:

```
    model_fit <- 
  felm(
    dependent_variable ~
      independent_variable1 +
      independent_variable2 +
      independent_variable3 +
      independent_variable4 + 
    |as.factor(year)+
      as.factor(month),
    data = df
  )
```

Here's the code that I'm using to tidy those results and the error message:

```
model_results <- tidy(model_fit, conf.int = TRUE, conf.level = 0.95, fe=TRUE)
Error: No tidy method for objects of class felm
```

I've already updated RStudio, as well as the lfe, broom, and tidytext packages. It is my understanding that the tidy function should tidy felm objects, and the tidy.felm function no longer exists.

How can I use the tidy function for felm objects? And, if I am unable to use that function, what other function can I use to tidy my FELM?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem after updating to R 4.0.3. An alternative to felm is feols from the package fixest, which has a tidy method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix the issue:

1. Restart R
2. Call the `broom` library when using the `tidy()` function

So, for example:

```
library(lfe)

mod <- felm(y ~ x1 +x2 | factor(id) | 0 | id, data)
broom::tidy(mod)
```